# Ajax post and Grails render causing page to refresh

Tags: ajax, grails, controller

So, I've got a controller set up with the following: -

```
def show(Long id) {
    def testObjectInstance = TestObject.get(id)

    if (!testObjectInstance) {
        redirect(action: "list")
        return
    }

    println("show object ID " + testObjectInstance.id)
    render(template: "show", model: [testObjectInstance: testObjectInstance])
}
```

I've then got a post with the following code :-

`function loadObject(objID){
    var pathPrefix = $("#fullPathPrefix").val();
    $.postJSON(pathPrefix + "testObject/show",{id : objID}, function(data) {
        $("#rightObjMgtPane").html(data);
    });
}`

I can see all the println's showing up as expected and the page even renders as expected but then suddenly the whole page refreshes for some reasons and I can't work out why.

I have another controller in another place which seems to work that has exactly the same render line in it and that works fine so Im at a loss.

Comment: I noticed after more digging that the whole process of rendering the template seems to be working ok and the new html is displayed, if I put an alert in after the `$("#rightObjMgtPane").html(data);` this shows up as well, but the minute I close that the whole pages refreshes, to the extent that if I preserve logs in the chrome dev tool all the previous entries in the network tab no longer show the html returned (but does beforehand), and if I don't preserve them the network tab completely empties and repopulates from scratch...!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
$.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: '/testObject/Show',
 data: '{"id":"objID"}',
 success: function(data) { 
  $("#rightObjMgtPane").html(data); 
 },
 contentType: "application/json",
 dataType: 'json'
});
```

Instead of

```
function loadObject(objID){
var pathPrefix = $("#fullPathPrefix").val();
$.postJSON(pathPrefix + "testObject/show",{id : objID}, function(data) {
    $("#rightObjMgtPane").html(data);
});
}
```

On the other hand, i need to warn you the use:

```
if (!testObjectInstance) {
    redirect(action: "list")
    return
}
```

Would render wherever you have in testObject/list